# Laplace distribution

Tags: distribution-theory, laplace-method

We know that Laplace distribution has a form of 
$f_x=\frac{1}{b}*e^{(-\frac{|(x-\mu)|}{b})}$

Is it true to call the $f_x=\frac{1}{b}*e^{(-\frac{|(g(x)-\mu)|}{b})}$ distribution as generalized Laplace distribution?